# Expand {product.variations}

Tags: commerce

In the product detail page I would like to display the price at the BOTTOM of the {product.variations}

Where can we alter the {product.variations} ?

Comment: Likely in a [preprocess function](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/what-are-preprocess-functions#:~:text=Preprocess%20functions%20allow%20Drupal%20themes,exposed%20through%20a%20preprocess%20function.)

Comment: @Clive, thanks. Can you guide on this particular issue? How would I move the price lower within {product.variations} using preprocess. See image https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fjxNTasnzMlivH9rmrJ9Wyo0FP597Tg7/view

Answer (score -1):

Go to /admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types, click Edit on your product variation type, click the Manage Display tab, here you can change the order of the fields on whichever display mode you are using.

Comment: Thanks. But Moving the price at the bottom in Manage Display does not put it where I need. See this image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fjxNTasnzMlivH9rmrJ9Wyo0FP597Tg7&usp=drive_fs